# Ошибка в swagger

Tags: golang, swagger

Не могу разобраться, почему команда:

```
swag init -d cmd/app/ --parseInternal --output api/openapi --parseDependency --parseDepth=1
```

Выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

```
2022/08/30 00:43:14 ParseFile error:/home/eurvanov/go/src/gitlab.sbermarket.tech/paas/content/operations/self-fee/internal/service/workers/payroll/split/split.go:10:50: expected ';', found '[' (and 1 more errors)
```

На файле:

```
package send

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/google/uuid"

    "gitlab.sbmt.io/paas/content/operations/self-fee/internal/pkg/outbox/job"
    "gitlab.sbmt.io/paas/content/operations/self-fee/internal/service/events"
)

func New(usecase sendUsecase) job.Runner[*events.PaymentNew] {
    return job.NewRunner(func(ctx context.Context, event *events.PaymentNew) error {
        id, err := uuid.Parse(event.ID)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        _, err = usecase.Do(ctx, id, event.FiscalizationRegistryId)

        return err
    })
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Дальнейшая проблема:

```
 swag init -d cmd/app/ --parseInternal --output api/openapi --parseDependency --parseDepth=1
2022/08/30 22:03:55 Generate swagger docs....
2022/08/30 22:03:55 Generate general API Info, search dir:cmd/app/
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x87dc68]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/swaggo/swag.(*PackagesDefinitions).parseFunctionScopedTypesFromFile(0xc0000127b0, 0xc00162cb00, {0xc0002a2170, 0x7}, 0xc01761b5f0)
        /home/eurvanov/go/pkg/mod/github.com/swaggo/swag@v1.8.5/packages.go:168 +0xa8
github.com/swaggo/swag.(*PackagesDefinitions).ParseTypes(0xc0000127b0)
        /home/eurvanov/go/pkg/mod/github.com/swaggo/swag@v1.8.5/packages.go:110 +0xc9
github.com/swaggo/swag.(*Parser).ParseAPIMultiSearchDir(0xc0001c02a0, {0xc0001b3fc0?, 0x1?, 0x0?}, {0x981e72?, 0x7?}, 0x1)
        /home/eurvanov/go/pkg/mod/github.com/swaggo/swag@v1.8.5/parser.go:362 +0x3bf
github.com/swaggo/swag/gen.(*Gen).Build(0xc0001b9920, 0xc0001bb040)
        /home/eurvanov/go/pkg/mod/github.com/swaggo/swag@v1.8.5/gen/gen.go:177 +0x5c9
main.initAction(0xc000189680?)
        /home/eurvanov/go/pkg/mod/github.com/swaggo/swag@v1.8.5/cmd/swag/main.go:151 +0x757
github.com/urfave/cli/v2.(*Command).Run(0xc000190c60, 0xc0001cc380)
        /home/eurvanov/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli/v2@v2.3.0/command.go:163 +0x5dc
github.com/urfave/cli/v2.(*App).RunContext(0xc0000c9520, {0xa56650?, 0xc0000280c8}, {0xc000024090, 0x9, 0x9})
        /home/eurvanov/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli/v2@v2.3.0/app.go:313 +0xb7d
github.com/urfave/cli/v2.(*App).Run(...)
        /home/eurvanov/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli/v2@v2.3.0/app.go:224
main.main()
        /home/eurvanov/go/pkg/mod/github.com/swaggo/swag@v1.8.5/cmd/swag/main.go:221 +0x5c5
```

Comment: Бинарник swag скомпилирован старой версией go, без поддержки типовых параметров: https://github.com/swaggo/swag/issues/1104#issuecomment-1015824888

Comment: Проблема в старой версии golang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы решить первую проблему, нужно обновить версию golang не менее чем до 1.18. Проблема в generics.

После возникновения следующей проблемы, нужно обновиться до версии 1.8.4 swag

[Здесь](https://devsday.ru/blog/details/94894) человек разбирает нечто подобное. Также в [issues](https://github.com/swaggo/swag/issues/1312) есть информация о том, что это может быть проблемой в 1.8.5. А в 1.8.4 этого нет.

Таким образом, основное решение -- это обновление golang до 1.18 и обновление swag до 1.8.4:

```
go install github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag@v1.8.4
```